# Open a popup when menu item is clicked on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio, popup

I want to open a popup when I press the ActionBar Button.

I have this file menu_menuscreen.xml in the menu folder, this is the Action Bar.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.flixarts.ar.englishnow.menuscreen">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Búsqueda"
        android:onClick="openPopup"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_user"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="Usuario"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

But I don't know where do I have to write the code to open the popup.

I have to write the code to open the popup button.
I think I have to write a onClickListener method
and create an xml file for the popup.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to do this following steps:

1. Inflate or Show menu in Activity
2. Add listener to your Menu Items

So Add following code in your Actvity

```
//Show Menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_menuscreen, menu);
    return true;
}

//Add Menu listener
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search){
        //this is Popup default
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Default Popup");
        builder.create().show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For popups please refer Google documentations. [Alert Dialog documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#java)